# How do I install odoo 14 community version in ubuntu 18

Tags: git, github, odoo, odoo-14

I am trying to install odoo 14 community version in ubuntu 18.04 but intead it installs the enterprise version.
I am cloning it from the odoo github repo using

```
git clone https://www.github.com/odoo/odoo --depth 1 --branch 14.0 /opt/odoo14/odoo
```

yet it install the enterprise version and asks me for a database subscription to register my database.

Comment: Follow this link. https://github.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript. You need to change IS_ENTERPRISE to FALSE  in script.

Comment: You can get it from nightly.com

Answer (score 0):

I've installed multiple instances following the guide here:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-odoo-14-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Answer (score 0):

Video Tutorial « Odoo 14 Installation Guide - Ubuntu 20.04 » https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIPoKXz6nrc

Answer (score 0):

please use this comand to pull the code
git clone https://www.github.com/odoo/odoo --depth 1 --branch 14.0 /opt/odoo14/odoo

Also check this tutorial on how install odoo 14 in ubuntu 18.04 and ubuntu 20.04
https://yardincsolutions.com/how-to-install-odoo-14-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options to install odoo, the first - if you are using a cloud provider like was - there exist ready odoo images created by [Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/odoo), and this is the Bitnami documentation for it - [link](https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/apps/odoo/)

The second option if you want a fresh installation, is to directly go with odoo official documentation and go with [source install](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/administration/install/install.html#source-install)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.